# A converse to Burnside's lemma?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

[Burnside's lemma](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379503007225), in its simplest version, says that if $(V,\rho)$ is an irreducible representation of a group $G$ on a finite-dimensional complex vector space, then ${\rm span}\, \rho(G) = {\rm End}\,V$.

Is the converse true? That is, if ${\rm span}\, \rho(G) = {\rm End}\,V$, can we conclude that $(V,\rho)$ is irreducible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if $W$ is a non-trivial subrepresentation, then $W$ is preserved under the
action of $\rho(G)$, so $\rho(G)$ cannot be all of $\text{End}\,V$.